# How to use Polarplot instead of Contourplot?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot[Power[x,1.5]-Power[1.65,0.5]*x+y^2==0,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},PlotPoints->100,MaxRecursion->1]
```

It's easy to get plot as below:
[image]
Then, I use `Polarplot` to plot the same thing,

```
p=Power[x,1.5]+y^2==Power[1.65,0.5]*x/.{x->r Cos[t],y->r Sin[t]}
foo=r/.First@Solve[p,r,Reals];
PolarPlot[foo,{t,-Pi,4Pi}]
```

There's no plot when use Polarplot.
How to use PolarPlot(or ParametricPlot) for this plot?

Comment: The "First" solution is simply useless. The second solution is more likely what you wanted.

Comment: Or add the constraint `r > 0` to `Solve` and there will only be only one solution.

Comment: If you take the second solution in your code, it is ok.  `p = Power[x, 1.5] + y^2 == Power[1.65, 0.5]*x /. {x -> r Cos[t], 
   y -> r Sin[t]};
foo = r /. Solve[p, r, Reals][[2]];
PolarPlot[foo, {t, -Pi, 4 Pi}]  `

Comment: @Akku14,why do you add `[[2]]` after ` Solve[p, r, Reals]`?

Comment: `[[2]]` is second part of expression. See in Help `Part` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
trans = TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
Power[x, 1.5] - Power[1.65, 0.5]*x + y^2, {x, y} -> {r, \[Theta]}]

(* -1.284523258 r Cos[\[Theta]] + (r Cos[\[Theta]])^1.5 + r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2*)

sol = r /. Solve[trans == 0, r][[2]](*Second solution*)

(* 4.70073691*10^-16 Csc[\[Theta]]^4 (-1. Cos[\[Theta]] \
(-1.063663016*10^15 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 
  2.732599766*10^15 Sin[\[Theta]]^2) - 
1. Sqrt[0. + 1.131379012*10^30 Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
 5.813130617*10^30 Cos[\[Theta]]^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^2])*)  

PolarPlot[sol, {\[Theta], 10^-9, 4 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: In `PolarPlot[sol, {\[Theta], 10^-9, 4 Pi}`,why do you set `10^-9`?why not `0`?

Comment: I don't understand `Second solution` in `Solve[trans == 0, r][[2]]`.What's the problem of my script?

Comment: @kittygirl. if `\[Theta] = 0` then is Indeterminate expression.Only for Second solution MMA give a nice plot.